# $\inf_Y[\sup(2x+2y:0<x<1)]$ How to approach this?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\inf_Y\sup_X f(x,y)$
Let $Y=(-1,0)$ and $X=(0,1)$ and $f(x,y)=2x+2y$
Let's start simply with $\inf_Y[\sup(2x+2y:0<x<1)]$
now here occurs the first problem for me, can I use the properties of $Y$ in this step, or would it be $\inf_Y[2+2y]$ or since i know that Y is negative i could finish here and say $\inf_Y[2]=2$
but the first approach would tell me it is: $\inf_Y[2+2y]=2-2=0$ since $Y=(-1,0) =>\inf_Y(2y)=-2$

So do I have to take sup of f(x,y) regardless of what Y is, which doesn't make sense. Maybe i need a proper definition for multivaraible sup and inf

Please give a comprehensive answer which approach is correct. Any explanation is appreciated

Comment: You cannot use the properties of $Y$ in the first step since "$\sup_X$" indicates that $y$ is held constant and $x$ varies in $X$. For any $y,\sup_Xf(x,y)=2+2y$. Then $\inf_Y$ indicates finding the infimum of $2+2y$ over $Y$, which is indeed $2+2(-1)=0$.

Comment: is sup(x,y) the same as sup x sup y ?

Answer (score 1):

The notation here is sloppy. It is ambiguous and forces the reader to make assumptions to be able to put any meaning to it. That is the source of your confusion. If this is exactly the notation you yourself are receiving, and it did not come with additional explanations, then you have my condolences. If this is the result of you short-cutting on the notation, then please stop. Don't take shortcuts on notation you do not thoroughly understand.

But the only reasonable interpretation of it that I see is
$$\inf\{\sup\{2x + 2y \mid 0<x<1\} \mid -1 < y < 0\}$$
Or to break it down, let $A_y := \{2x + 2y\mid 0 < x < 1\}$, then you are looking for
$$\inf\{\sup A_y\mid -1 < y < 0\}$$

Clearly, for each $y, \sup A_y = 2 + 2y$, so this becomes
$$\inf\{ 2 + 2y \mid -1 < y < 0\}$$
and so the answer is $0$.